# Does somebody know how to show video stream on ios with ionic and webrct cordova-iosrtc-plugin?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I am not able to added video stream cordova-plugin-iosrtc ... I am work with Ionic v1 and cordova-plugin-iosrtc.

**Video** **html**:

```
<video id="video"  preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer"></video>
```

**Video add Stream Code**:

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector('video#video')

function gotVideoStream(stream) { // navigatorUserMedia result

    videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);

}
```

**My video tag, after stream added:**

```
<video id="video" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer" src="polyblob:1"></video>
```

Error:

Refused to connect to polyblob:1 because it does not appear in the connect-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:blobinternal:///5fb0fa90-7fc5-4ab4-9867-b987b3449645
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/null

I have tried everything about content-security-policy and not work.

I have no idea about solve this probem

Thanks!!

Comment: @EILoko36 Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem, and can't seem to find a workaround.